# PHP echo ID and Pop Up form

Tags: php

I have a pop-up form when user clicks "update", there should be a pop up form where user should be able to update but the pop up does not appear because the "a href" has "echo" in the id value. See below: echo $orderId

```
<a href="#id=<?php echo $orderId ?>" id="btn">Update</a>
```

But if I delete the `<?php echo $orderId ?>`part, for example `<a href="#id" id="btn">Update</a>` the pop up works but echo wrong ID.

Below is the form

```
<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="id=<?php echo $orderId; ?>"></a>
<div class="popup">
<form method = "post" action="">
    <div>
        <label for="Order ID">Order ID:</label><?php echo $orderId ?>
    </div><br>
    <div>
        <label for="Order Date">Order Date:</label><?php echo $orderDate ?>
    </div><br>
    <div>
        <label for="Order Total">Order Total:</label><?php echo $totalAmount ?>
    </div><br>
    <div>
        <label for="Preparation Status">Preparation Status:</label>
            <select name="preparationStatus"/>
                <option value="<?php echo $preparationStatus; ?>">Default(<?php echo $preparationStatus; ?>)</option>
                <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                <option value="Prepared">Prepared</option>
            </select>
    </div><br>
    <div>
        <label for="Payment Status">Payment Status:</label>
            <select name="paymentStatus">
                <option value="<?php echo $paymentStatus;?>">Default(<?php echo $paymentStatus;?>)</option>
                <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                <option value="Paid">Paid</option>
            </select>
    </div><br>
        <input type="submit" id="btn" name="submit" value="Save" />
        <a class="close" href="#close"></a>
</form>
```

It only echoes `id="id=1"`

How can I make the popup form appear?

Comment: inside your div.popup is there any tags with id="x"

Comment: no there is no tag with id="x" @nbin

Comment: Have you checked the HTML your PHP is generating (right click -> view source)? How does your popup work? (hint - it doesn't work automatically - you're using *some* sort of library/plugin you haven't told us about)

Comment: Can you post whole code of div.popup ?

Comment: yah as @h2ooooooo said Give further and full neccessary info.

Comment: @nbin i just edited the question

Comment: What are you using as listener for the popup? I assume that you have some JS that is listening for when the a link is clicked?

Comment: Nope. There is no JS, just CSS. @Epodax